Inconsistent window.scrollTo(0, 0) Behavior
I'm using Barba.js for page transitions on my website, and I want the scroll position to always reset to the top of the page during transitions. I've added window.scrollTo(0, 0) in the afterEnter hook, but it doesn't consistently work. For example, when transitioning from the homepage to the corporate page, it only works about 2 out of 10 times.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
history.scrollRestoration = "manual"

barba.hooks.afterEnter(() => {
  console.log("window scrollTo 0, 0");
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});

barba.init({
  transitions: [{
    name: 'default',
    async afterEnter() {
      console.log("window scrollTo 0, 0");
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    },
  }]
});

Despite seeing the log message every time, indicating that the code is executed, the scroll position doesn't always reset as expected. Also i noticed if i add setTimeout (100ms) to the scrollTo it works more consistently but it is still not consistent, for example it works 5-6 times out of 10 tries. and I can see it's scrolling up. I want it to start right at the top.
What could be causing this inconsistent behavior? Thank you

Their might be some other scroll event that interferes with yours.

some browsers try to scroll you automatically to the position you were in the previous page. especially if you use back button. web search suggest history.scrollRestoration = 'manual'; might help
